# Delphi supported version

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-5

I have some applications which built using Delphi 5.0. Currently as far I know Delphi 5.0 is no more supported by Embarcadero. I am planning to upgrade my application to next supported Delphi version. I am trying to find out if Delphi 7.0 is supported by Embarcadero or not? As other Delphi version might need Unicode conversion issue I am looking for Delphi 7.0 and recompile it.

Got this link: - http://support.embarcadero.com/article/37740

Not getting what exactly means De-supported column.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question - do you need advice on how to do this, or do you need the software?

Comment: Delphi 7 is no longer sold by Emba, you may be able to get limited support from other users via their newsgroups.  If you want to use a copy, one possible way is to purchase a current Delphi version and that *may* give you a licence to use D7, and if it does, you can then download D7 from Emba's site.  But you should check with your local Emba distributor  what version you would need to purchase and which SKU.  Btw, your q is not a good fit for SO and may get closed as off-topic here.

Comment: Delphi 7 is still officially supported by Embarcadero or not?

Comment: Means they are still providing official license for Delphi 7.0?

Comment: De-supported means: "not supported any more"

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name Means Embarcadero don't support Delphi XE7 also which is launched 2 years back?

Comment: D7 is nearly 20 years old, but now you are asking about XE7, a completely different product?

Comment: There's probably little point in you upgrading from. Delphi 5 to Delphi 7. What problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a vendor support question, and we're not Embarcadero. Contact Embarcadero Sales and ask them questions related to which products are and are not available now.

Comment: @David- Currently my applications built using Delphi 5.0 which is no longer supported. Also Embarcadero don't provide license for Delphi 5.0. Now I am planning to move application to supported version by Embarcadero with minimal efforts. And If Delphi 7.0 is still supported  then its just need to rebuild code in Delphi 7.0

Comment: Thanks Ken. Agree.

Comment: Why do you care about support. Have you availed yourself of much support recently? Porting to Delphi 7 is probably pointless. What do you gain.

Comment: @David Its primary for Auditing purpose.

Comment: You asked if delphi 7 was supported. You have your answer. What more is there to say.

Comment: The last non-unicode Delphi is D2007. Which is supported according to the table. I don't know what that means.

Comment: @ Sertac Akyuz - good catch. Thanks

Comment: I don't think your link could be any more clear than it already is. Did you want us to read it for you?

Comment: When buying the most recent version, you used to get access to some older ones, especially Delphi 2007, as well. No idea if this is still the case. You'll have to ask Embarcadero about that.

Comment: @dummzeuch: Yes, that is still the case. But you must buy the newest and then have 6 months time to get the older versions.

Comment: unless u use some Delphi-specific components (that often got dumped by Borland/CG/EMBT in later versions anyway) i'd suggest trying to move to Lazarus/CodeTyphon, at least it is free :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi 7 is not supported. It has not been supported since 2008 according to the article you linked. De-supported in that table gives the date where support ended.

Comment: Ok. got it. But just wondering as Delphi XE7 is also in De-Supported column that support is also ended means. Thanks All for comments. It give me some direction to think.

Comment: XE7 is no longer supported. The table is clear. Support ended in April 2016.

Comment: That downvote is unfortunate, considering it's a perfect answer.

Comment: @JerryDodge: I have the impression sometimes answers are downvoted because they don't say what the reader wants to see, even if what they say is perfectly fine and correct.

Comment: I expect that the answer was downvoted because the question is so poor. Which is fine in my view.

Comment: Even more sad the question actually got an upvote too.

Comment: I have to say, I think the two upvotes on this answer are pretty questionable.